# Ios images and labels keep loading while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, sdwebimage

I'm writing a demo to show user's tweets.

**The question is:**
Every time I scroll to the bottom and then scroll back, the tweet's images and comments are reloaded, even the style became mess up. I know it something do with **dequeue**, I set Images(which is an array of UIImageView) to [] every time after dequeue, but it is not working. I'm confused and couldn't quite sleep....

Here is core code of my TableCell(property and Images set), **which provide layout:**

```
class WechatMomentListCell: UITableViewCell{
    
    static let identifier = "WechatMomentListCell"
    
    var content = UILabel()
    var senderAvatar = UIImageView()
    var senderNick = UILabel()
    var images = [UIImageView()]
    var comments = [UILabel()]


  override func layoutSubviews() {
//there is part of Image set and comments
        if images.count != 0 {
            switch images.count{
            case 1:
                contentView.addSubview(images[0])
                images[0].snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
                    make.leading.equalTo(senderNick.snp.leading)
                    make.top.equalTo(content.snp.bottom)
                    make.width.equalTo(180)
                    make.height.equalTo(180)
                }
            default:
                for index in 0...images.count-1 {
                    contentView.addSubview(images[index])
                    images[index].snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
                        make.leading.equalTo(senderNick.snp.leading).inset(((index-1)%3)*109)
                        make.top.equalTo(content.snp.bottom).offset(((index-1)/3)*109)
                        make.width.equalTo(90)
                        make.height.equalTo(90)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if comments.count != 0, comments.count != 1 {
            for index in 1...comments.count-1 {
                comments[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                contentView.addSubview(comments[index])
                comments[index].snp.makeConstraints{(make) in
                    make.leading.equalTo(senderNick)
                    make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(index*20)
                    make.width.equalTo(318)
                    make.height.equalTo(20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my ViewController, **which provide datasource**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let tweetCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WechatMomentListCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? WechatMomentListCell else {
            fatalError("there is no WechatMomentList")
        }
        
        let tweet = viewModel.tweetList?[indexPath.row]
        for i in tweet?.images ?? [] {
            let flagImage = UIImageView()
            flagImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: i.url))
            tweetCell.images.append(flagImage)
        }

        for i in tweet?.comments ?? [] {
            let flagComment = UILabel()
            flagComment.text = "\(i.sender.nick) : \(i.content)"
            tweetCell.comments.append(flagComment)
        }
        return tweetCell
    }
```

The Images GET request has been define at ViewModel using Alamofire.

**The firsttime is correct. However, If I scroll the screen, the comments will load again and images were mess up like this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in your tableview cell. in cell you have two variables like this.

```
var images = [UIImageView()]
var comments = [UILabel()]
```

Every time you using this cell images and comments are getting appended. make sure you reset these arrays every time you use this cell. like setting theme empty at initialization.

Comment: so this is not because dequeue? I still don't know what's going wrong with my code.

Comment: I need to know where are you calling your fetch function and how you appending data and when you are reloading your tableview after getting the response back.

Comment: The fetch function is in view Model(delegate to binding data), and I reloading my tableView once fetch finished. Then I append my data in VC by implements tableView().

Comment: I have edited the answer please have a look.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want! BTW, it also need to use `removeFromSuperview` in my codes.